# Extracting multiple values from a string with RegEx

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have an input string that's generated as in following example:

```
string.Format("Document {0}, was saved by {1} on {2}. The process was completed 
{3} milliseconds and data was received.", 
"Document.docx", "John", "1/1/2011", 45);
```

It generates string looks like this then:

```
Document Document.docx, was saved by John on 1/1/2011. The process was completed 
45 milliseconds and data was received.
```

Once such a string is received from a different application, what would be the easiest way to parse with regex and extract the values `Document.docx`, `John`, `1/1/2011`, `45` from it.

I am looking for the easiest way to do this as we will have to parse a number of different input strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
private static readonly Regex pattern =
    new Regex("^Document (?<document>.*?), was saved by (?<user>.*?) on " +
        "(?<date>.*?)\\. The process was completed (?<duration>.*?) " +
        "milliseconds and data was received\\.$");

public static bool MatchPattern(
    string input,
    out string document,
    out string user,
    out string date,
    out string duration)
{
    document = user = date = duration = null;

    var m = pattern.Match(input);
    if (!m.Success)
        return false;

    document = m.Groups["document"].Value;
    user = m.Groups["user"].Value;
    date = m.Groups["date"].Value;
    duration = m.Groups["duration"].Value;

    return true;
}
```

It might be worth refactoring to return a composite type that contains all of the information you want instead of using `out` parameters.  But this approach should still work.

To use this code, you would do something like this:

```
var input = "...";

string document, user, date, duration;
if (MatchPattern(input, out document, out user, out date, out duration)) {
    // Match was successful.
}
```

Comment: awesome, you save my day :-)

Comment: trying to find python equivalent :/